# Adding a profile to a child container does not replicate in the other child containers in an ensemble?

Tags: java, jbossfuse, karaf, fabric8

I have recently started working on fabric8 in which I have created an ensemble of three fabric servers - node1, node2 and node3. Each fabric server has a child preferably   node1-child1, node2-child1 and node3-child1 respectively.

I want to add a profile to all the child containers. I thought because they are in a cluster, adding a profile in one child container will replicate the profile in other child containers as well. But that does not happen!

Is there a way I can achieve the above without specifically going into each container and adding the profile?

Comment: You are correct in your assumption, adding a profile to one fabric server will propagate it to the other servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a profile to one child container will not automatically add it to other child containers. In that case, all child containers in the cluster will always be duplicates of each other, which is not desirable.

You have to add the profile to every child container that has to run the contents of the profile. Once that is done, if you change anything in the profile, all containers with that profile will update automatically.